# I'm trying to make a method that reads a bunch of numbers from data into an image

Tags: java, arrays, drawimage

```
public static void readDataIntoImage(int image[][], Scanner input) {
    for() {
        for() {
        }
    }

}
```

I have to make a method that reads a bunch of numbers into an image from a different file. A hint was given that i need to use nested for loops for the 2D array. I just don't know how to fill in the for loops correctly.

Comment: Do you recall how to iterate over a 1D array?  If you do, you're (literally) halfway there.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < image.length; ++i) for (int j = 0; j < image[0].length; ++j) image[i][j] = ...;`

Comment: use `image.length` and `image[i].length`

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array is simply an array of arrays.  The simple solution is to write:

```
public static void readDataIntoImage(int image[][], Scanner input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image[i].length; j++) {
            // Your code
        }
    }
}
```

If you're not worried about tracking your position in the outer array, it may be slightly more efficient to iterate over the array of arrays as follows:

```
public static void readDataIntoImage(int image[][], Scanner input) {
    for (int[] row : image) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            // Your code
        }
    }
}
```